# Make an instantiable list of Widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

### I want to instantiate a Widget based on an int.

```dart
const List<Widget> WIDGETS = <Widget>[
  Widget1,
  Widget2,
  Widget3,
  Widget4,
];

final int index = 1;

Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(builder: (BuildContext context) => WIDGETS[index](hey: index))));
```

However, I am getting the following error in the Widget list:

`The element type 'Type' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. dart(list_element_type_not_assignable)`

I don't want to use `dynamic` or something similar, is there any way to declare that these are Widget `Type`s?

The JS similar would be `typeof`.

---

### This is possible:

```dart
void a() {
  print('a');
}

void b() {
  print('b');
}

const List<Function> EXAM_SCREENS = <Function>[
  a,
  b,
  a,
  a,
];
```

Why isn't my scenario as such?

> Edit: Just to clarify, I need to pass dynamic arguments to these widgets. `Widget1` needs the `hey` argument which is generated in its own Widget.

Comment: Are you init the Widgets? From what you write you're passing a list of Types, if you would like to init you need to call its constructor like this `Widget1()`

Comment: I'm going to answer

Comment: @LorenzoImperatrice I edited my question if it helps, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Didn't saw it sorry, i'm going to update my answere now, anyway what do u mean with "dynamic arguments" ??

Comment: The index is generated in another Widget, I don't have access to it until the `Navigator.pushReplacement` function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are not Widget until you initialize them, instead functions doesn't need to be initialized as they act like a variable (you are passing the pointer to the function).

So in this way:

```dart
const List<Widget> WIDGETS = <Widget>[
  Widget1,
  Widget2,
  Widget3,
  Widget4,
];
```

you're storing a list of Type, then if you try to change them like this you'll not get any errors.

```
const List<Type> WIDGETS = <Type>[
  Widget1,
  Widget2,
  Widget3,
  Widget4,
];
```

For doing what you ask is necessary to radically change the approach by using a method to create the desired widget, to this method pass the index as parameter (or any parameters needed for choose the right widget to create) and, based on the parameters, the method will return the right Widget.

```dart
Widget _chooseTheRightOne(int index, dynamic hey) {
  switch(index) {
     case 0: Widget1(hey: hey); break;
     case 1: Widget2(hey: hey); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: But how you will initialise these ? It will throw error here `WIDGETS[index](hey: index)`

Comment: Just as @MidhunMP said, `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.`

Comment: You have to radically change the approach by using the factory pattern, or factory method pattern. You pass the index and the method create and return the object for you.

Comment: Using a method would make me remove the `const` keyword, allocating the Widgets every time I call the method. I want to get the item from the list without having to allocate it every single time.

Comment: This is the most clean way to do it. If you prefere you can make a list of already allocated widget with a `GlobalKey`associated to them to access instance variables and modify them.

Comment: The last one is an anti pattern and isn't raccomanded at all, I'll write it in the answer

Comment: @Zeswen anyway for use the const keyword the list has to be static, and, as before, I don't raccomand it